# Retrofit2/OkHttp3: REST webservice does not specify characterset

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, content-type, okhttp

I am accessing a webservice that are not able to specify content-type nor character set for the content I consume.

Is there a way, using retrofit2 (or okhttp3 client interceptors), to add information about this so that received content can be processed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Retrofit you can use the `@Headers` annotation:

For instance: 
`@Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")`

You could then (if you always know the Content Type) set your Interface to be:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("widget/list")
Call<List<Widget>> widgetList();
```

https://square.github.io/retrofit/